# Is there a way to embed a static field in a java class at compile time based on ant buildfile?

Tags: java

Let's say that my project has a main class. I'd love to have

```
public static final String version = "0.0.0.1";
```

However, I don't want to have to manually set the version, as my ant build file has the version present. Is there any way to insert this value based on the value present in the build file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to [write the version number out to a property file](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) (or alternatively the Manifest file) using Ant, and in your Java code [read the value of that field from the property file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) instead of hard-coding it.

It's of course possible to add the field to the class before (by changing the source file) or after compilation, but that's probably unneeded effort and might result in hard-to-version source code.

Comment: Yes, I have done this in my project where we can pass version information from Ant task (define as a property in a properties file) which can be used in my Java application. It is much easier this way since we can edit the property in the properties file whenever we need to change the version information.

Answer (score 1):

There's the built-in [ReplaceTokens](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replacetokens) filter chain.

See the [filter chain docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) for details.